# How to check if a tensor is empty in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I have part of my code as following:

```
class_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name="condition_checking")
row_index = tf.where(class_label > 0)
```

I want to check when row_index is empty to write the following

```
loss_f_G_filtered = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=y1_filterred, labels=y__filtered), name="filtered_reg")

if row_index == []:
  loss_f_G_filtered = tf.constant(0, tf.float32)
```

However, I do not know how to check if `row_index` is an empty tensor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
is_empty = tf.equal(tf.size(row_index), 0)
```

Comment: I just solved it in another way but this is way much simpler. thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can use `tf.cond`:

```
idx0 = tf.shape(row_index)[0]
loss_f_G_filtered = tf.cond(idx0 == 0,
                            lambda: tf.constant(0, tf.float32),
                            lambda: ...another function...)
```

Comment: thank you @walkerlala, the problem is that the condition never become true, I added the explanation in the down

Answer (score 0):

```
    loss_f_G = 

tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y1_filterred, labels=y__filtered), name = "filtered_reg")
    idx0 = tf.shape(row_index)[0]
    loss_f_G_filtered = tf.cond(tf.cast(idx0 == 0, tf.bool), lambda: tf.constant(0, tf.float32), lambda:loss_f_G)
```

The problem is that idx0 == 0 is never true even when row_index = [].

[image]